# Prevent JAR from being imported into Eclipse Java project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java project which is heavily used by all sorts of other Java and Android projects. The project contains some JAR libraries which shall be used by all projects, except for the Android one (in fact the Android project is a Android library project to be precise).

I marked the JARs as "export" in the Eclipse build path preferences of the Java project. However, the Android project shouldn't import these libraries (as they are Java libraries which make use of some classes which are not available on Android), but it shall import the rest of the code (which doesn't really use the libraries, but they are stored in there for convenience reasons and to ensure, that all other projects use the same library.

How can I prevent the JARs from being exported to the Android projects?

Comment: I don't understand the question. In eclipse for a given project you have to explicitly add a jar to your classpath. So the question is why are you JARs being automatically added?

Comment: The JAR is imported as it is part of the project the Android project depends on. Therefore I don't have to manually add it to the project (and unfortunately cannot remove it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent all jars from being exported so that only the common project is a dependency for each project that needs it.

Then you can change the build path of each project to only include its necessary jars through the add jar.. dialog in build properties.

That's the easiest way.

A more extreme way would be to move to maven and then eclipse will only include the jars you specify in the pom - though that's a load of extra work for not much gain.

Alternatively, you could split the android specific code into a android-common separate project and then make your common project depend on it and export it - then your android project could rely on this android-common project instead of the existing common project.

Comment: These are some neat ideas - will probably go with the third one.